# Azure Mobile App targeting Linux database

Tags: linux, database, azure, azure-mobile-services

Is it possible to use xamarin forms and azure Azure Mobile Service to sync data online/offline but with the database hosted on a linux server outside the Azure platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can’t use On-prem database hosted on Linux server with Azure Mobile App.

For windows server, you can use Hybrid Connection to achieve this scenario: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/docs/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-hybrid-connections-get-started.md.

But Hybrid Connection client is not yet available for Linux Server.

Comment: Good point Swikruti. I went through your link and Hybrid Connection might be the solution for me. But assuming that my Windows Server (with SQL Server Express) is on a Virtual Machine running on Linux, can it work with this configuration?